# mysqli_stmt_prepare fails but file is uploaded to phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html

I have this php photo gallery, however my "mysqli_stmt_prepare" statement seems to be failing in someway. However, when I check my DB, the files that are in accordance to the upload rules, I created in my code, have been uploaded.

The message I get each time I upload a file to the DB is the one corresponding to a failed "mysqli_stmt_prepare", namely as in the code:

echo "SQL statement failed! 1"

```
<?php

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $newFileName = $_POST['filename'];
    //sets the file name to "gallery"
    if (empty($_POST['filename'])) {
      $newFileName = "gallery";
    //adds hyphens to empty spaces
    } else {
      $newFileName = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $newFileName)); 
    }

    $imageTitle = $_POST['filetitle'];
    $imageDesc = $_POST['filedesc'];

    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $fileName = $file['name'];
    $fileType = $file['type'];
    $fileTempName = $file['tmp_name'];
    $fileError = $file['error'];
    $fileSize = $file['size'];

    $fileExt = explode(".", $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "pdf");

    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
      if ($fileError === 0) {
        if ($fileSize < 200000) {
          $imageFullName = $newFileName . "." . uniqid("uniqID", false) . "." . $fileActualExt;
          $fileDestination = "../gallery/" . $imageFullName;


          include_once "dbh.inc.php";

          if (empty($imageTitle || $imageDesc)) {
            header("Location: ../gallery.php?upload=empty");
            echo "You didn't include the Image Title and Image description!";
            exit();
          } else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM gallerytrexatek";
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
              echo "SQL statement failed! 1";
            } else {
              mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
              $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
              $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
              $setImageOrder = $rowCount + 1;

              $sql = "INSERT INTO gallery (titleGallery, descGallery, imgFullNameGallery, orderGallery) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
              if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                echo "SQL statement failed! 2";
              } else {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $imageTitle, $imageDesc, $imageFullName, $setImageOrder);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                move_uploaded_file($fileTempName, $fileDestination);

                header("Location: ../galleryInPHP.php?upload=success");


            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        echo "File Size is way to big";
        exit();
      }
    } else {
      echo "You had an error with the file";
      exit();
    }
  } else {
    echo "The file type you tried to upload is not allowed!";
    exit();
  }
}
?>
```

I expect the file to upload without problems. It seems I am overlooking something rather simple.

Hint: There are 3 files connected to this one. 
1. The gallery.php where the form exists for images to be uploaded
2. The one which is pasted here
3. the DB handler file

Comment: try re-writing your code using `PDO` it will be much simpler

Comment: Yeah I will eventually, but first I need to get the basics right here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do'h, there was a problem with one of the file handler files.